# Android ServerSocket accepts a wi-fi hotspot

Tags: android, sockets, wifi, serversocket, hotspot

I have an Android device that is running as an access point (a.k.a. Wi-Fi hotspot) and it is running this code:

```
serverSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);

serverSocket.setReuseAddress(true);

while (RUNNING) {
    try {
        final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
```

I will have some other client device connect to this device's Wi-Fi hotspot, and try to connect to the socket, and it will not be able to.

The access point's IP address is something like 192.168.43.1, so I will try to connect from the client device to 192.168.43.1:8080 and it will not work.

**However**, if both devices are connected to another Wi-Fi network, the `serverSocket.accept();` will work just fine! I am using port 8080.

Do I need to tell the server socket to accept on the interface "ap0"? (Can I do that?)

I changed the port to 8988 and now it works just fine. Is it a firewall issue on the android device?

Any ideas how to navigate this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Yes you need to open socket on the server side also.

You should try the Android Example `WiFiDirectDemo` accessible in Android legacy: `\Android\android-studio\sdk\samples\android-19\legacy`  just import it into your enviroment and give a try..

Comment: I changed the port from 8080 to 8988 and now it works. Now I want to know how to mek it work on port 80! =)

Comment: @ChrisVollo ports under 1024 are reserved for system. Why do you need port 80?

Comment: Found a solution. I changed the iptbles to redirect all traffic on port 80 to port 8080.